# why is latency growing

Tags: replication

I have a 4.4TB database that I've been transactionally replicating to 2 different subscribers just fine.
Yesterday I added a 3rd subscriber that is all flash drives to test how much better it will be with all flash drives.
The latency on the original 2 subscribers is just fine/normal/sub5seconds.
However latency on the flashonly subscriber is growing and growing and growing.

Any idea what a "duh" check would be?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: what platform?  SQL Server?  MySQL? Something else?

Comment: If we are talking about SQL Server, I have found this repltalk article to be good for troubleshooting Transactional Replication performance:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrissk/archive/2009/05/25/transactional-replication-conversations.aspx